# A family of four definite integral, are they doable?

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $$I_{\mp n}=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^2}{1\mp e^{\sin(x^n)}} \,dx,~~ n=1,3.$$ We can visualize four integrals: $$I_{+1}, ~~I_{-1}, ~~I_{+3}, ~~I_{-3}.$$ Are these four integrals doable and convergent?

Comment: Yes and the result write $\frac {\color{red}{42}} k$ where $k$ is a whole number and ${\color{red}{42}}$ is *"the Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything"*

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: furthermore, it appears that $k$ is a *pentatope* number (Wikipedia).

Comment: Thanks Rocherz for the editing. Claude and Yves must be joking!

Comment: All four integrals turn out to be $1/3$ as shown by JG in his solution. It is important to note that $I_{+,1}$ and $_{+,3}$ are proper definite integrals. $I_{-,1}$  and $I_{-,3}$ are improper definite integrals. $I_{-,1}$

Comment: All four integrals turn out to be $1/3$ as shown by JG in his solution. It is important to note that $I_{+,1}$ and $_{+,3}$ are proper definite integrals. But $I_{-,1}$  and $I_{-,3}$ are improper definite  integrals. $I_{-,1}$ has integrand which exists only as limit $x \rightarrow 0 $ and it is converges to $1/3$. In the case of $I_{-,3}$, the integrand near $x=0$ goes as $1/x$ so $1/3$ is the principal value of ${I_{-,3}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For odd $n$ as in the problem, $\sin x^n$ is odd, and any odd function $f$ satisfies $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{x^2 dx}{1\mp e^f}=\int_0^1 x^2\left(\frac{1}{1\mp e^{-f}}+\frac{1}{1\mp e^f}\right) dx=\int_0^1 x^2dx=\frac13.$$In the case of $I_{-3}$, the integrand is $\sim-\frac{1}{x}$ for small $x$, so this treatment obtains a Cauchy principal value (specifically, case 1) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation) with $-a=c=1,\,b=0$).

Comment: Good, but you have to do/think a lttle more!

Comment: @ZaharAhmedDSc Are you referring to the fact that $\frac{x^2}{1-\exp\sin x^3}$ diverges to $\pm\infty$ as $x\to 0^\mp$? The integrand is asymptotically $-\frac{1}{x}$, so $I_{-3}$ has to be understood as a Cauchy PV.

Comment: Yes, please add it to your solution.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc OK; done.